# Colored mark in margin notes in the middle of the \marginparsep

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, marginpar, marginnote

It's code, thanks for @Harish Kumar,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{255,255,170}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
\colorbox{background}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1in}
\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}R_A+R_B &=\frac{R_3(R_1+R_2){R_1+R_2+R_3}\marginnote{Some margin note here}
\end{empheq}
\clearpage
\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}R_A+R_B &=\frac{R_3(R_1+R_2)}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\marginnote{Some margin note here}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

It's code very well working. That I want add to colored mark in margin notes in the middle of the \marginparsep. Odd page \blacktriangleleft and even page \blacktriangleright. Like that,

```
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\newcommand{\marginmacro}{\marginnote{ {\color{red}$\blacktriangleleft$} Some margin note here}}
\else
\newcommand{\marginmacro}{\marginnote{Some margin note here {\color{red}$\blacktriangleright$}}}
\fi
```

That is, add first attach red color **\blacktriangleleft** in the middle of \marginparsep add second attach **margin not** in the \marginnote area in the odd pages. In the other hand, add first attach **margin not** in the \marginnote area, add second attach red color **\blacktriangleleft** in the middle of \marginparsepin the even pages.

For example, for odd pages.
[image]

I'm sure this is a duplicate of another question that I just can't find. So, does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go again:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,ifoddpage,showframe}   %% remove showframe.

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{background}{RGB}{255,255,170}
\usepackage{empheq}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
\colorbox{background}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1in}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{%
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\marginnote{\hspace*{-0.55\marginparsep}\makebox[0pt]{\textcolor{red}{$\blacktriangleleft$}}\hspace{0.55\marginparsep}#1}
\else
\marginnote{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\dimexpr\marginparwidth+0.77\marginparsep\relax][r]%
 {\textcolor{red}{$\blacktriangleright$}}}\hfill#1}
\fi
}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
     R_A+R_B &=\frac{R_3(R_1+R_2)}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\mymarginnote{Some margin note here}
  \end{empheq}
  \kant[2]
  \clearpage
  \kant[1]
  \begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
     R_A+R_B &=\frac{R_3(R_1+R_2)}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\mymarginnote{Some margin note here again}
  \end{empheq}
  \kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's perfect working. Thanks for your helping me and everone. I would like to thank you for support, new beginners like us. I hope, one day I will help everyone as/(like) that you do.

Comment: But \usepackage{kantlipsum} not working. Error: Emergency stop. When click, l3int.sty line:58 \cs_new_eq:NN \if_case:w        \tex_ifcase:D. I erased about with all <kant>. When erased, not problem, it's working. It doesn't matter it for me. Because kernel source is working.